# How to create an AzureRunAsConnection in Automation using ARM Templates

Tags: azure-automation, azure-rm-template

Am working on the ARM Templates, using this am trying to create an Azure Automation account along with AzureRunAsConnection. Am able to create Automation account successfully but coming to AzureRunAsConnection I didn’t find any way to create it with the help of ARM Templates. While searching on it, I known that there is no chance to create connection using ARM Templates. Can you give me any suggestions for this issue to create a connection?

I referred [link](https://blog.tyang.org/2017/10/15/new-powershell-module-for-azure-automation-azureserviceprincipalaccount/)

Answer (score 0):

The Run As Account can be created only if you have the administrator or the co-admin permissions and this can be used to create and deploy run books.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the ability to do this with ARM templates is still "under review" as a feature at MS:

[See the item for azure feature improvement here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/18864241-creation-of-run-as-accounts-using-arm-template)